# How to find relationship between two objects Django in large codebase

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm working on a new large codebase.  There are a ton of models with foreign key relationships and I'm having a hard time keeping them all in my head as I click through the different foreign key relationships.  I'm using PyCharm so it's nice to be able to click through the different relationships. The problem is if I have two objects that I'm are connected, i'm basically reduced to clicking down seemly endless relationship paths, which is time consuming and confusing.  A lot of times I'll find my self many levels deep from the object I started at and run into a dead end, then I'll have to chase back up the tree and try another path.

I tried to use [this](https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/generate-uml-class-diagrams-from-django-models/) tool in an attempt to auto draw a uml, but the uml has so many lines between the different objects, I can't tell which ones are connected and it also outputs a png, so I can't search for a model.

Does anyone have a recommendation on how I can do this more easily?

Comment: Usually if there are that many models, the modeling is *too complex*, and thus should be cleaned: defining apps such that there is only a limited number of connections between two apps, and each app thus has models that are almost only connected to other models of the same app.